# Отправка смс на почту

Tags: php, email, form

как сделать чтоб при окончание регистрации на почту приходило смс о подтверждения пароля и логина, а после подтверждения приходил пароль и логин к сайту?

Comment: на почту письма приходят, а не смски))

Comment: "смс" — "на почту"? Это как?

Comment: точно письмо, а не смс))

Answer (score 1):

Примерно так. В регу:

```
mail($to, 'Подтверждение регистрации на сайте site.com', "Подтвердите ваш аккаунт, нажав на <a href=\"http://site.com/confirm.php?email={$to}\">эту ссылку</a>");
```

confirm.php:

```
$password = 'password'; // генерируем пароль
mysql_query("UPDATE `users` SET `confirmed` = 1, `password` = '{$password}' WHERE `email` = '{$_GET[email]}'");
mail($_GET['email'], 'Ваши регистрационные данные от site.com', "Ваш пароль: {$password}");
```

И не забываем про безопасность. А вообще, [прочитайте это](http://true-coder.ru/php/podtverzhdenie-registracii-po-email-na-php.html).

Comment: стоп, но мне не надо генерировать!

Comment: Но если пользователь сам ввёл пароль, то он должен был его знать, и передавать его не обязательно :)

А если мы учитываем возможность пользователей с амнезией, то тогда в confirm.php делаем SELECT, сохраняем пароль в $password и отправляем на ту же почту, к которой он присоединён.

Answer (score 0):

:) Но если Вы хотите уведомить клиента об успешной регистрации через СМС, то подключите мобильный телефон к серверу и передавайте программно АТ-команды в телефон (работа с СОМ портом), который автоматически отправит СМС. Естественно при регистрации посетитель вашего сайта должен ввести свой номер, а Вы, в свою очередь, должны сделать проверку номера.